# Share a variable through out Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I have a variable.

`$key_test = 123456789;`

I want to be able to access this 1 variable anywhere in my app even in config files, models, controllers, and views.

I've tried adding it in my `boot()`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\VSE, App\CURL;
use View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $key_test = 123456789;

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

---

I've tried to access it in one of my config file. I kept getting `null`.

```
<?php

dd($key_test); <---- null

return [ ... ];
```

How do I access that variable in my config file?

Did I do it right in my `boot()`?

Comment: You can save it in cookies or sessions as you required

Comment: How do I do that ? Where do I do that ? in my boot() in my Service Provider file ? Feel free to give more hints or answer.

Comment: that's depends upon your flow or logic where is best you can use it

Comment: This is my flow. I need to query my database first, get the result of that, store in a variable, and share that variable. How can I achieve that ? If you can help me with that, you save my life. :)

Comment: in my case if i have login application than i will save it on success login
if i have solo application than i will do it in constructor of class and make object of it in each controller

Comment: if you make database call every time it make your application slow

Comment: ouch why so complicated ...

Comment: not soo complicated it is the simplest way

Comment: How can I do that only time not everytime ? How I just want to access that variable in one of my config file ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a helper method for config.

```
config(['key_test'=>123456789])
```

Then access it through the same way,

```
config('key_test')
```

Comment: Yeah I prefer config over .env, unless it really is environment specific.

Comment: My thoughts exactly @devk.

Comment: Where exactly should I place this line of code `config(['key_test'=>123456789])` ? in my `boot()` ?

Comment: @lan : I agree with you guys as well, .env file should only be use for environemnt specific.

Comment: @ihue Place it in your Service Providers boot method

Comment: I tried that and I got null printing out. How can I debug it further ?

Comment: I did `public function boot()
    {
        config(['key_test'=>123456789]);
    }
`

Comment: Then, call it, `<?php
dd($key_test);

return [... ] ; `

Comment: Result : `null`

Comment: You need to call `config('key_test')` not `$key_test`

Comment: @lan OP asked about getting this variable even in config files. config() won't work here, only env() will. Here's the quote `I want to be able to access this 1 variable anywhere in my app even in config files`

Comment: @lan : Yes that what I did. `public function boot() { config(['key_test'=>123456789]); }`

Comment: @lan  I didn't include `$` when I config it.  I only include `$` when I try to call it. Why ? Am I not suppose to do that ?

Comment: No because you are not calling a variable, you are calling a function which returns a value @ihue.

Comment: @ihue Maybe you should learn the basics of PHP / Laravel, the documentation for `config()` is at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-config

Comment: I did as your answer and I kept getting `null`

Answer (score 3):

Put this variable into the `.env` file:

```
VAR=123456789;
```

Then you'll be able to access it with `env('VAR');` from config files, models, controllers and other classes.

Comment: I like your suggestion about .env file. But what if I need to query my database first, get the result of that, store in a variable, and share that variable. How can I achieve that in .env ? Do you have other suggestions fo me ?

Comment: .env are only really good for static variables, you might be better off using the `config()` helper for site wide configurations.

Comment: @ihue in this case just set variable to the config with `config(['var' => 123456789])` and then you'll be able to get the variable value with `config('var')`. But it won't work in you want to get this value in config files.

Comment: @lan I agree that `config()` is better, but OP asked about getting this variable even in config files. `config()` won't work here, only `env()` will.

Answer (score 1):

you have some choice here, for global variable, session, file, db, or in the memory with redis or memcache.

Comment: I like your suggestion aboutglobal variable, session, file, db, or in the memory with redis or memcache. But what if I need to query my database first, get the result of that, store in a variable, and share that variable. Can I still achive when doing one of those above that you mentioned. If so, where should I do that ? in what file ? in my service provicer ?